# Topology of SL(2,R)

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups

I am interested in visualizing the Lie group $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ topologically.
Writing a matrix as $A = \begin{pmatrix} x+w & -y+z\\ y+z& x-w \end {pmatrix}$
I could identify a matrix with determinant $1$ lying on the hypersurface $x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2=1$ or on the complex curve $|a|^2-|b|^2=1$ ($a,b \in \mathbb C$). But how to see the topological form of this manifold? Is there a nice identification?

Comment: It isn't a complex curve - the equality $|a|^2 - |b|^2 = 1$ is one real condition, not one complex condition.  So you expect the group to be three real-dimensional.  By the way, you are very close to having a direct answer using the first description you gave. Try to show that $X^2 - z^2 - w^2 = 1$ describes a copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 8):

In general, a connected Lie group $G$ is diffeomorphic to its maximal compact subgroup $K$ times some $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $SO(2) \times \mathbb{R}^2$ (use Gram-Schmidt).

Comment: ... which in turn is diffeomorphic to the interior of a solid torus (the Cartesian product of a circle and an open disk).

Comment: Really? Does this mean that $Sp(2N,R)$ is isomorphic to $R^{N(N+1)}$ times $U(N)$? Do you have any reference on this?

Comment: @LFH: diffeomorphic as a smooth manifold, but not isomorphic as a Lie group.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's very helpful - I just asked a related questions, but this confirms what I had already looked at... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can parameterize the hypersurface $x^2+y^2-z^2-w^2=1$, so we will get $x=\cosh t.cosr$, $y=\cosh t.\sin r$, $z=\sinh t.\cos s$, $ w=\sinh t.\sin s$ and then by this parametrization we would have a homomorphic mapping between$ S^1 ☓D^2$ and the above hypersurface. Can any one state the explicit rule of that function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).